# Creating a dynamic range in VBA

Tags: vba

Obviously, my code does not yet have the necessary loop in it, but I would like to create a loop which Range("b3:gs3") from line 3 and updates it the following recursive fashion:

```
Range("b3:gs3")
Range("b6:gs6")
Range("b9:gs9")
.
.
.
Range("b720:gs720")
```

I can code the loop, but am having difficulty coding this change in range values.

Help would be much appreciated.

Ron

```
Sub Box()

    Dim curCell3 As Range

    For Each curCell3 In Sheets("Sheet 2").Range("b3:gs3").Cells  'This is the problem

    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("6").Activate
    Range("B1").Select

    Do While ActiveCell.Value <> curCell3.Value
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
    Loop

            ActiveCell.Offset(44, 0).Select
            ActiveCell.Copy
            ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet 2").Activate
            curCell3.Select
            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
            ActiveCell.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

    Next curCell3

ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("6").Activate
Rows("3:3").Delete
ActiveCell.Offset(2, -199).Select

End Sub
```

Comment: It's unclear what you want to achieve in the end....

Comment: I want to know how to code the range. I wish to keep the rows the same but change the columns. For instance, if range(x,y), where x = b3 and y =gs3, I want the next loop to return x1 = b6, y1 = gs6, and the next to return x2 = b9, y2 = gs9, and so on

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Box()

    Dim curCell3 As Range
    Dim rw As Long, f As Range, rngSrch As Range

    Set rngSrch = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("6").UsedRange.Columns(2)

    For rw = 3 To 720 Step 3

        For Each curCell3 In Sheets("Sheet 2"). _
             Range("b" & rw & ":gs" & rw).Cells

            Set f = rngSrch.Find(curCell3.Value, , xlValues, xlWhole)
            If Not f Is Nothing Then
                curCell3.Offset(0, 1).Value = f.Offset(44, 0).Value
            End If

        Next curCell3

    Next rw

End Sub
```

Comment: Wow, that's incredible Tim. Thank you so very much